# SQL counts one more row than it has

Tags: sql, count, row

I have these tables:

**comments**

```
uid
id
pid
```

**pages**

```
pid
user
```

**users**

```
id
rank
.
.
.
```

and this query:

```
SELECT
   u.*, 
   count(p.id) as 'pages',
   count(c.id) as 'comments' 
FROM 
  `users` u 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `pages` p ON p.user = u.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` c ON c.uid = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

For some reason it shows 2 comments for a user when he has only 1.

Is there a problem in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the user is multiplied by his number of pages, and then by his number of comments.  One way to fix that is `count(distinct ..)`:

```
count(distinct p.id) as 'pages',
count(distinct c.id) as 'comments'
```

Comment: it worked!! thanks alot i will accept your answer when the site lets me.. can you explain to me a bit more about that the user is multiplied by his number of pages? what does it mean?

Comment: The first join retrieves one row for each page.  If a user has 2 pages, that's 2 rows.  The next join retrieves comments for each of those two rows!  So if the user has 3 comments, you end up with 6 rows.